# Need some help setting up threading in a javafx app

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx

I need some help picking the optimal threading pattern for my project. I wanted to hear an opinion from java experts and their take one this.

The app has a list of devices, stored in an observable list.

1. App initializes, the UI thread runs
2. ui thread calls the unitActiveTask thread to start monitoring if devices are active, this runs always in the background.
3. The user can call certain services and tasks while the other 2 threads run.
   examples of tasks and service (not really sure what the difference is between service and task)

   - delete device from list
   - upload a file to the device (firmware, configuration) (can take a very long time)
   - generate configuration (generate a properties file that holds arbitrary values, takes 1-5 seconds)
   - few other similar actions

You can assume only the unitActiveTask should not block. Other tasks can block the user until they are done. The only thing that should always stay responsive is the ui, unitActiveTask can potentially be paused.

Comment: Can you create a specific question? It's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: the question is how would you thread this? maybe some links to some resources. Because there are so many variants. Tasks, runnables, threads, executors etc. Then there s relevant data structures like blocking queues, futures, locks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably too broad for this forum; however, see if this is enough to help:

A [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) represents a one-off task that is intended to run in a background thread. It can return a value and can throw exceptions. It has callback methods which are executed on the FX Application Thread (so are intended to be used to update the UI) which are invoked at various points in its life-cycle, for example `setOnSucceeded(...)` and `setOnFailed(...)`. Additionally, it has various `update...(...)` methods which update properties on the FX Application Thread. Each `Task` instance can only be executed once.

A [`Service`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) has similar functionality to a `Task` but is intended to be reusable. As such, it has additional methods such as `reset()` and `restart()`. It works by creating and managing `Task` instances (via a `createTask()` method, which you need to implement) and executing them on one or more background threads.

A `ScheduledService` is a `Service` which can generate its `Task`s at specified time intervals.

For your scenario:

Item 2: since this is a single thread running for the duration of your application, it is ill-suited to a `Task` (which is designed to execute and return a value) or `Service` (which is effectively just a collection of `Task`s). For this, you might consider using a `ScheduledService` to poll the devices at regular intervals, or you might simply create a thread and execute it in the background. In the latter case, you should call `setDaemon(true)` on the thread so that it does not prevent application exit. If you do choose the `Thread` option, any changes that need to be made to the UI as a result of code executed in the thread need to be invoked back on the FX Application Thread, which you can do with a call to `Platform.runLater(...)`. If you use a `ScheduledService`, you can do this using the callback methods on the service, or on the tasks it creates.

Item 3: [Create an `Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) suitable for your needs (or more than one if appropriate). In the event handlers which trigger the appropriate tasks, create a task, configure it by setting handlers for `onSucceeded` and `onFailed` (if necessary), and execute the task in the executor. You can disable parts of the UI before submitting the task, if appropriate. The `onSucceeded` handler can re-enable those parts of the UI as well as process the results of the task.